# Can't start MySQL5.5 on Ubuntu 12.04 - “dpkg: dependency problems”

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, mysql5

This appears to be a common problem on 12.04. I've tried everthing in [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1998260&page=3) including:

```
sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get autoclean

sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-client-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5 mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5

sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

I still get the same old error. Installing/starting MySql5.5 looks like this:

```
apt-get install -f mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
mysql-server is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) ...
120907 21:37:15 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
120907 21:37:15 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
120907 21:37:15 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
120907 21:37:15 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
120907 21:37:15 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
120907 21:37:15 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
120907 21:37:15 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
120907 21:37:15  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
120907 21:37:16 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 154164236
120907 21:37:16  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
120907 21:37:16  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 154164236
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.

Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
```

In addition, `dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5` returns `/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: mysql-server-5.5 is broken or not fully installed`

The ultimate goal here is installing and configuring Gitorious to work with Redmine but I believe the problem is isolated to Ubuntu 12.04 and MySql5.5

Comment: I've also tried both answers here to no avail http://askubuntu.com/questions/134574/fixing-broken-myslq-server-package-after-upgrade-to-12-04

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my case, andrewcaveman's solution did a job.

> I had the same issue. Tried the apt-get clean, autoclean, remove and apt-get install mysql-server-5.5 Same error would keep coming up.
>
> I removed everything a second time, tried again, still the same problem.
>
> This is what worked for me, though I was doing an install and not an upgrade, so I didn't care about the existing database.
>
> **I removed all the mysql application again, then I went and deleted my /var/lib/mysql directory. 
>   Keep in mind, if you have an existing database there, you will lose it. You might want to move it to another location.**
>
> After removing that directory, I installed again and it worked perfect. So something in the /var/lib/mysql directory was my problem. See if that works for you.

source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12362816&postcount=2

Comment: Link-only answers are a no-no due to possible link rot in the future.  Please include pertinent information in your answer.

Comment: This worked!!!!!!! YEAAAA

Comment: this one worked for me as well (Ubuntu 13.04)

Comment: It worked for me too, but in kubuntu you must first remove all mysql-server-core dependent software before it works and install it AFTER it worked